# Silverstripe Control with Pos/Interation -1

Tags: php, silverstripe

I would like to be able to control/loop through my data to generate the following:

```
Loop 1 - name
Loop 2 - name1
Loop 3 - name2
- etc
```

I know I could use the Pos within a control although I need this to start at 0. If only I could do a simple math calculation within the SS template. I can't think how I could achieve this.

Comment: I figured it out today $Pos(0)

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it below (with enough description) and then, when SO allows, you can select it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be solved by passing the starting number to the position.

```
$Pos(0) // Start at 0
$Pos(99) // Starts at 99
```